# 要素(図面）をクリックしたらfadeOutさせたい

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

開発環境：
Windows10 64bit
ブラウザ：GoogleChrome 69.0.3497
エディタ：Brackets(ﾘﾘｰｽ 1.13 ﾋﾞﾙﾄﾞ 1.13.0-17696)
使用言語：HTML/CSS/Javascript/jQuery

<概要>
jQueryの勉強中です。
「Webページの図面(丸*1、四角*2)をクリックしたら、その図面がフェードアウトしていく」という動きをさせるため、fadeOutを指定しましたが、図面をクリックしてもフェードアウトしません(何も起こりません)。どこを修正したらよいでしょうか？

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        #circle {
            width:150px;
            height:150px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background-color:green;
            margin:10px;
        }
        .square {
            width:150px;
            height:150px;
            background-color: red;
            margin:10px;
        }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <!--
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        -->
        <script src="jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>

        <div id="circle"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>

        #HTML要素をクリックしたらフェードアウトさせたい
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("div").click(function(){
                $(this).fadeOut();
            })

        </script>     
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: まずはブラウザのJavaScriptデバッガーなどを使って、jQueryが正常に読み込まれているかどうか確かめてみてください。

Comment: コメント頂きありがとうございます。

>$(this).fadeOut();<のうち、"fadeOut()"を"css("display","none")に書き換えると正しく動きましたので、jQuery自体はブラウザに読み込まれていると思います(という認識ですが、合っていますか？)。なぜか「fadeOut()」が動作しないです。

Comment: エラー内容(Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fadeOut is not a function)で調べたところ、stackoverflow(英語版)で似たような質問をされてる方がいました。
「アニメーションエフェクトは"スリム"なjQueryだと使えないから、"フル"のjQueryを導入すればいい」とのことでしたので検討してみます。ひとまず解決とさせて頂きます。コメントを頂きありがとうございました。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934446/why-does-jquery-throw-the-error-fadeout-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 1):

エラー内容(Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fadeOut is not a function)で調べたところ、stackoverflowで似たような質問をされてる方がいました。それによれば 「アニメーションエフェクトは"スリム"なjQueryだと使えないから、"フル"のjQueryを導入すればいい」とのことでしたので検討してみます。ひとまず解決とさせて頂きます。コメントを頂きありがとうございました。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934446/why-does-jquery-throw-the-error-fadeout-is-not-a-function